# avoid enormous network payloads

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, chunks

Hi I have a Vue project and I'm trying to improve the performance. I used Lighthouse to run a performance test and one of the suggestions is I have to avoid enormous network payloads. I looked at it and there are many js files with the name of my webpackChunkName (from router) but combined and separated with the symbol `~`. For example
`/js/usersetting~dashboard~settings~productsettings~userpr….js`. There are a few JS files like this. I wonder what these are and is there anything I can do to reduce or remove (I don't know) these? Appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: [Reduce number of files served by Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63908525/381282) - maybe this ?

Comment: or this: [Vue Router loads all my lazy-loaded components at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66670617/381282)